# Load data using RCaller

Tags: java, r, rcaller, gwmodel

I want to load data which is embedded in an R package. I use GWmodel package and want to load LondonHP data. But when i try to load the data using RCaller in Java, the xml return is :

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
</root>`

This is my code to load the data :

`code.R_require("GWmodel");
code.addRCode("data(LondonHP)");
caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("londonhp");`

Can you guys give me solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see in **R** console that the londonhp object is in type of **S4** :

```
> typeof(londonhp)
[1] "S4"
```

So, it has some slots :

```
> slotNames(londonhp)
[1] "data"        "coords.nrs"  "coords"      "bbox"        "proj4string"
```

You can access its elements using the **@** operator:

```
> londonhp@data
```

So you need to handle londonhp@data, not londonhp itself.